# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.EvalTag

Tags: jboss7.x

I am getting this exception while running spring application on Jboss 7.1,the jar containing the class is present there(Spring mvc-3.0.5 release )

```
15:49:11,354 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
15:49:14,742 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
15:49:15,354 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.0.Final "Thunder" starting
15:49:27,980 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
15:49:27,995 INFO  [org.xnio] XNIO Version 3.0.3.GA
15:49:28,308 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.3.GA
15:49:28,403 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] JBoss Remoting version 3.2.2.GA
15:49:28,496 INFO  [org.jboss.as.logging] JBAS011502: Removing bootstrap log handlers
15:49:28,606 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) JBAS013101: Activating Security Subsystem
15:49:28,621 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 35) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
15:49:28,668 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 43) JBAS011940: Activating OSGi Subsystem
15:49:28,715 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 42) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
15:49:28,824 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 52) JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
15:49:30,917 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS013100: Current PicketBox version=4.0.6.final
15:49:30,965 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (JBoss IronJacamar 1.0.7.Final)
15:49:31,465 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
15:49:32,043 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
15:49:33,060 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
15:49:36,259 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-4) Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-localhost-127.0.0.1-1234
15:49:40,308 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management.AbstractServerConfig] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.0.1.GA
15:49:43,016 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\Program Files\jboss_server\jboss-as-7.1.0.Final\standalone\deployments
15:49:43,080 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015003: Found SprinWebJboss.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called SprinWebJboss.war.dodeploy
15:49:43,220 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS017100: Listening on localhost/127.0.0.1:4447
15:49:43,220 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS017100: Listening on /127.0.0.1:9999
15:49:43,877 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
15:49:44,566 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015874: JBoss AS 7.1.0.Final "Thunder" started in 38848ms - Started 135 of 206 services (70 services are passive or on-demand)
15:49:44,707 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "SprinWebJboss.war"
15:49:47,211 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."SprinWebJboss.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."SprinWebJboss.war".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "SprinWebJboss.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_04]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_04]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_04]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011093: Could not load component class org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.EvalTag
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:113)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:54)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.EvalTag from [Module "deployment.SprinWebJboss.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:111)
    ... 7 more

15:49:47,242 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "SprinWebJboss.war" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"SprinWebJboss.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"SprinWebJboss.war\".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"SprinWebJboss.war\""}}
15:49:47,259 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment SprinWebJboss.war in 13ms
15:49:47,259 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."SprinWebJboss.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."SprinWebJboss.war".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "SprinWebJboss.war"

15:49:47,259 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"SprinWebJboss.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"SprinWebJboss.war\".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"SprinWebJboss.war\""}}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you find which jar is this class coming from: 
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.EvalTag

Can you unzip the ear and re-check that the jar Spring mvc-3.0.5 release is part of the packaged ear.